# What's the difference between simple and deep groove ball bearing

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bearings

What's the difference between simple ball bearing and deep groove ball bearing?

**EDIT:**
  I read about them in my textbook of design. The book has only mentioned that there are teo types of ball bearings. One, simple and the other, deep groove. No images or explanation have been provided. When I search for their images on google, Images of both the types of ball bearings look the same.

Comment: So, images of which bearings you are looking at would help.

Comment: @SolarMike See I've edited the question

Comment: Find another text book then or check out bearing manufacturers online - they have excellent images...

Comment: There are ***much*** more than "two types of ball bearings" - Thrust Bearings, Self-Aligning, Angular Contact, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Without an idea of which bearings you are looking at, a deep-groove ball-bearing is able to control a higher axial load, but for larger loads a taper-roller bearing can or is used.

An example is the wheel bearings on cars - some have roller bearings and are not adjustable, others use taper roller bearings that have nuts and locking washers to set the free-play.